# Windows authentication inconsistencies with "LOGON_USER" server variable

Tags: asp.net, iis, forms-authentication

Another developer and I are both working on the same ASP.NET web app. The application uses Forms authentication, but the IIS virtual directory is configured with both "anonymous access" and "integrated Windows authentication". This mirrors the production site which authenticates as required.

A potentially key difference between our two setups is that he is on Windows 7 and IIS 7, whereas I'm on Windows XP and IIS 5 (for my sins).

Initially when we both run the app, the variable...

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

...is false. This I'd expect because we're configured with Forms authentication. The app then redirects to a WindowsAuth.aspx page. That page checks the Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] server variable and, if this isn't null or empty, uses it to automatically sign in.

The issue is, on my PC Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] is always empty. To me this is correct since we have anonymous access enabled. But on my colleague's PC, and in production, the variable holds the user's username. I cannot understand why this is. Is there a difference between IIS 5 and 7 in this regard? Otherwise, can you explain this? Obviously I want my setup to reflect other environments but upgrading to Windows 7 is a last resort at this point.

Comment: Could it be a difference in your web browser settings? Try accessing your site from his machine, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306359

To populate the LOGON_USER variable when you use any authentication mode other than None, you can deny access to the Anonymous user in the  section of the Web.config file. To deny access to the Anonymous user in the  section, follow these steps:

Change the authentication mode in the Web.config file to anything other than None. For example, the following entry in the Web.config file sets the authentication mode to Forms-based authentication:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms" />
```

To deny access to the Anonymous user in the Web.config file, use the following syntax:

```
<authorization>
   <deny users = "?" /> <!-- This denies access to the Anonymous user -->
   <allow users ="*" /> <!-- This allows access to all users -->
</authorization>
```

If you are using Windows authentication, you can also use the following steps to resolve this problem:
Change the authentication mode in the Web.config file to Windows as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

In the Internet Services Manager, right-click the .aspx file or the Web Project folder, and then click Properties.
If you clicked Properties for the Web Project folder, click the Directory Security tab. If you clicked Properties for the .aspx file, click the File Security tab.

Under Anonymous Access and authentication control, click Edit.
In the Authentication methods dialog box, clear the Anonymous Access check box, and then select either the Basic, the Digest or the Integrated (NT Challenge/Response) check box.
Click OK to close both dialog boxes.